# Selecting all values inside an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, class

From what I understand, `document.getElementsByClassName` returns something like an array object.

How can I modify all returned objects without using jQuery?

Let's say I want to change `border-color` of all divs that have "class1" applied to them?

```
<div id="container">
  <div class="class1">Hello</div>
  <div class="class2">World</div>
  <div class="class1">Hello</div>
  <div class="class2">World</div>
</div>
```

Comment: You can iterate over the collection with regular `for loop`.

Comment: What code is needed. The question is completely understandable without it

Comment: @mplungjan: what is wrong in adding the relevant code.

Comment: Ok. Added code for you. I still think it is not necessary to answer the question as seen in the answers

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Even jQuery will loop over the returned objects. Hiding the `for` (or `while`, `each` or `map`) loop is just syntax sugar but it's still a loop underneath it all:

```
var class1 = document.getElementsByClassName('class1');
for (var i = 0; i < class1.length; i++) {
    class1[i].style.borderColor = 'green';
}
```

Comment: @mplungjan: Yes, that's exactly how to do it "in one go..". Even jQuery does this. Hiding the for (or while, or each or map) loop is just syntax sugar but it's still a loop underneath it all.

Answer (score 1):

In one go === in one line?

```
[].forEach.call(document.getElementsByClassName("class1"), function(c) { c.style.borderColor = "red"; });
```

Comment: "in one go" doesn't mean in one line in normal English

Comment: @slebetman Thank you for the insight. In fact it's an interpretation, since it's not clear what OP meant with "in one go".

Comment: And I was the one that added "in one go" and removed it since it seems to have confused some